# Embed fields disappear after discord bot goes offline (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, embed, pycord

So, I was making a command **that adds fields to an embed**. It works fine (the embed fields stay intact) but **if the bot is rerun or goes offline, it resets again**. Is there any way to **make the added fields permanent in the embed** so that even if the bot goes offline it keeps track of all the added fields?

```
 cne=discord.Embed(title="Computer Science - Notes")
 @commands.slash_command(description="Add a file to collection.")
    async def add(self, ctx, subject, collection, title, link):
       global cne
       if subject == "Computer Science":
         if collection=="Notes":
           cne.add_field(name=f"{title}", value=f"[Click here]({link})", inline=False)
```

Comment: Fetch the embed from the message on startup?

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Could you pls tell me how exactly? I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Which message is it adding to? Just make an on_ready listener that fetches that message, and sets your variable to the embed from that message.

Comment: okay I will try doing that, thank you